# Paginating search results ordered by distance in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, google-cloud-functions

I am writing Firebase Cloud Function which takes in an a "subject" (eg: math etc) parameter and "originCoordinate" parameter and returns a list of users ordered by distance from the origin coordinate.

### Currently, the solution I have for this is to:

1. Query all users who teach that subject
2. Calculate their distance from the origin coordinate
3. Sort the results by distance
4. Return 10 users

This is the current implementation:

```
let searchResults = []
const originCoordinates = req.params.coordinates

const userCollection = db.collection('users')
const searchQuery = userCollection.where('subjectsTaught', 'array-contains', req.params.subject)                                       

searchQuery.get()
    .then(data => {                                               
        data.forEach(doc => {
            const docData = doc.data()                                
            searchResults.push(                       
                {
                    "username" : docData.username,
                    "name" : docData.name,
                    "description" : docData.description,
                    "avgRating" : docData.avgRating,
                    "distance" : calculateDistance(originCoordinates, docData.coordinates),
                    "avatarUrl": docData.avatarUrl
                }                  
            )
            // Orders results by distance, returns next 10 records using last username as cursor
            searchResults = seek_paginate(searchResults, req.params.lastRecordUsername)
        });            
        return res.json(searchResults);  
    })        
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The problem with this is that, it has to query all 1000 math tutors each time this function is called, using up a lot of document reads.

I was wondering if there's a better a way to go about doing this?

Is it possible to somehow transfer this code into the Firestore's Indexes, so that I could paginate it normally using the inbuilt startAfter() function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Firestore pagination in Cloud Functions, you will have to arrange for the client to send the values required in a call to `startAfter()`. There is no easy way around this - the client needs to inform the backend about how to get the desired page of data.